# analysing C# project on sonar using csproj files

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Can I analyse a C# project in sonar using its project file(.csproj) instead of solution file(.sln). Is there any way to do this in sonar. Do i need to configure my pom.xml file in some ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible for the moment.

However, creating a "fake" SLN file should not be a big deal.